# removing a HTML list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

So... I'm making a page that has notifications, a mark as read button and a mark all as read button, when i try to activate the mark all as read using my loop

```
let markAllAsRead = () => {
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("markAsRead");

  let notifications = document.getElementsByClassName("notification");

  let newValue = Number(counter.innerText) - 7;

  if (newValue < 0) {
    newValue = 0;
  }

  console.log(buttons);

  counter.innerText = newValue;

  for (let i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++) {
    notifications[i].classList.remove("new");
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].remove(buttons[i]);
  }
};
```

it only will eliminate one element yes and other no like so:
[live test of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfUGx.gif)

Comment: Please rephrase this into a question

Comment: `querySelectorAll("markButtons");` does that selector return anything??

Comment: no, it returns a empty nodeList

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm back just to update this one, the problem it self was

```
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].remove(buttons[i]);
  }
```

instead of make it look for a "default loop" I made "i" be equal to the HTMLCollection lenght, then i>= 0; --i

```
for (let i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    buttons[i].remove();
  }
```

making it, the function works as it should removing all the buttons of mark as read.